# Numpy vectorization of 2D array differences

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'd like to vectorise the difference of two M x N arrays across different slices in NumPy. Something like this:

```
dA = A[1:,:] - A[:-1,:]
dB = B[:,1:] - B[:,:-1]
C = dA * dB
```

But since `dA` is (M-1) x N and `dB` is M x (N-1), it's not a valid operation.

In other words, is there a way to vectorise this loop in NumPy?

```
for i in range(M-1):
    for j in range(N-1):
        C[i,j] = (A[i+1,j] - A[i,j])*(B[i,j+1] - B[i,j])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
dA = A[1:, :-1] - A[:-1, :-1]
dB = B[:-1, 1:] - B[:-1, :-1]
C = dA * dB
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use numpy.diff function

```
    np.diff(A, axis=0)[:, :-1] * np.diff(B, axis=1)[:-1, :]
```